# Time logging system

Tags: java

I want to implement a project where I check system timings whenever I am logged in. If I enter the office and log in my system the I should get the time and also when I go for a break I just lock my PC and go so at that time time should stop and again when I login it should start. Basically it should show me the total time I was logged in my computer/PC. after seeing the reply i got an understaning that i should create a batch file and load in startups. what should be in batch file.

Comment: Change your title of question and give a link at your question it would be more understandable and nice. Try to explain your question more.

Comment: This is my actual question:

I want to implement a project where I check system timings whenever I am logged in. If I enter the office and log in my system the I should get the time and also when I go for a break I just lock my PC and go so at that time time should stop and again when I login it should start.

Basically it should show me the total time I was logged in my computer/PC.

after seeing the reply i got an understaning that i should create a batch file and load in startups. what should be in batch file.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Do you want to store these values anywhere? Are you still intending to use Java or are you looking to do this purely in windows batch? If Java, I'd just call a class that gets the system time and publishes it somewhere with a note for login and who. and then when you log out you could publish something similar.

Comment: Thanks Chris.I wanted to store the time in excel and at the end of the day i should get teh total duration.I wanted to implement using Java.i can get the current time. But i dont want to record the timing when system is logged off.How can i implement this using java.Please help

Comment: It might help if you could tell us what pars of this problem you *do* know how to do, and what part you are stuck on. As it stands it reads like a request for someone else to write your program for you, which may not go over well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the the DOS command `echo "LOGIN","%DATE%", "%TIME%" >> timelog.csv` in a batch file. If you format the output properly you can open it in MS Excell and add formulas to calculate your time.

You may be able to find a screen saver that will run arbitrary batch commands on screen lock/unlock to record your breaks.

Comment: Thanks Chris i will try and come back if any queries.